# Custom headview does not fill the entire screen

Tags: ios

In the image below you can see that my `headview` does not fill all the available space.

[image: Custom headview]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I edited your post so that the image is properly inserted and so that it is easier to understand. Can you provide a sample of your code so that we can help you? Do not copy paste all your app, please provide only the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the header its the footer which is displayed. Add these lines it will fix your issue.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
   return 1.0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] ;
}
```